# Adjust height of parent with transition when content changes?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I have an outer div like so:

```
.text-bg2 .text2.first{
    width:75%;
    height:auto;
    min-height:50%; 
    transition:all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
}
```

Inside I have a p element, which is added via jQuery when a user clicks on a selection in my submenu. So when he clicks lets say "stackoverflow" a text for "stackoverflow" is being faded in. The problem is, that the height of my .first just changes without a nice smooth transition, when someone clicks on a menupoint which fades a p element in which is higher than 50% of the height. Can someone explain why the transition doesn't work here? Is there a pure css workaround? I know I could do this via .outerheight with jQuery, but I really want to know if there is any other solution to this?

jsfiddle added: http://jsfiddle.net/kzbyd15k/1/
Note: jsfiddle is not optimized, but its enough to see the effect. Also, i know the jquery isnt optimal, but i was too lazy to rewrite it.

Comment: It would be helpful to see an example. Can you set up something at jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 2):

Add height:0 to your .text2 class and configure transition for it, when you click on any item calculate the child height and asign to a parent .text div

```
$current.parent().css('height', $current.height() + 'px')
```

Here is the fork of your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ddm7e4mt/

Comment: The thing is I wrote I know I could do this via .height in jQuery, I wanted to know if there is another way